# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Tags: java, task

My program is supposed to print all numbers from 1111-9999 where all numbers are evenly divisible by `n`. However, I am getting an exception stating that I'm dividing by zero. Why is this?

```
 package NestedLoops;

  

         import java.util.Scanner;

      public class SpecialNumbers {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        for (int i = 1111; i < 9999; i++) {
            int firstdigit = i % 10;
            int seconddigit = (i / 10) % 10;
            int thirddigit = (i / 100) % 10;
            int fourtdigit = i / 1000;
            if ((n % firstdigit == 0)&& (n % seconddigit == 0) && (n % thirddigit == 0) && (n % 
              fourtdigit == 0)) {


                  System.out.printf("%d ", i);
              }
            }
        }
      }
```

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgNrF.png)

Comment: Most probably you need to calculate firstdigit % n

Comment: Consider the case where `i = 2021`. In that case, `n % thirddigit` is `n % 0`, which is division by zero. Also, I think that the directions say that the digits must be evenly divisible by `n`, but you're actually checking to see if `n` is evenly divisible by the digits. Or am I misreading the directions?

Comment: Also, is my edit ok?

Comment: yes thanks for your help.i fix my code and everything is ok.

Comment: Can you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is happens because the `%` operator are using dividing to calculate the result, so `anyNumber % 0` will throw an `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`.
To prevent this,  check if your digits are equal to 0 before the if statement.